# Displaying 3 different tables with 3 different buttons

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to have 3 buttons and when the user clicks on one of them it displays the corresponding table and hides the other two.

I have tried using getting element by id and then setting the display to none or block based on what the current state of the table is.

```
<div onclick="myFunction()" id="u362" class="ax_default">
</div>
<div onclick="myFunction2()" id="u317" class="ax_default">
</div>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var a = document.getElementById("tbl");
    var b = document.getElementById("tbl2");
    if (a.style.display === "none") {
      a.style.display = "block";
      b.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      a.style.display = "none";
      b.style.display = "none";
    }
  }

  function myFunction2() {
    var a = document.getElementById("tbl");
    var b = document.getElementById("tbl2");
    if (b.style.display === "none") {
      a.style.display = "block";
      b.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      a.style.display = "none";
      b.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>
```

The actual results are just really weird and have no resemblance to what I am trying to do.

Comment: Can you create a JsFiddle for your problem?

Comment: What do you mean by weird? Also, you don't have all of your code posted, but it looks like both buttons will do the exact same thing.

Comment: Shrey Gupta, did you try my solution out below? It does seem to solve one of the issues you posted about in your comment below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not shown all of your code and are not explaining what you are wanting to do. Right now both of your functions are acting the same way, because you are operating on both tables each time.

If I can "guess" as to what you might want, it would be that when you click on button 1, then it will show table 1 and hide table 2. If you click on button 2 then it will show table 2 and hide table 1. If you look at your code below this is not what you are doing. You are showing both tables or hiding both tables in both instances.

To fix this you can do something like this:

```
<div onclick="myFunction()" id="u362" class="ax_default">
</div>
<div onclick="myFunction2()" id="u317" class="ax_default">
</div>

<script>
  var a = document.getElementById("tbl");
  var b = document.getElementById("tbl2");

  function myFunction() {
    a.style.display = "block";
    b.style.display = "none";
  }

  function myFunction2() {
    a.style.display = "none";
    b.style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

Notice you do not need an if/else in each function unless you are wanting the buttons to toggle on and off, in which case you may only need one button.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet of your code cleaned up. As @kojow7 noted above they basically do the same thing just based off 1 table or the other. 
Things to note:
1) use slightly more descriptive variable names in your functions
2) create a css class that does your hiding so that you can simply test for that. when possible try to keep your js from handling styling
3) i replaced your if else with ternary if's. but in reality if all you are doing is toggling the class hidden then you could replace the if with a toggle.
4) instead of adding the onclick listener in your html it should be added via your js. try not to muddy your html with js concerns.

```js
document.getElementById('u362').addEventListener('click', function () {
  const tbl1 = document.getElementById("tbl1"),
    tbl2 = document.getElementById("tbl2");
  tbl1.classList.contains('hidden') ?
    (tbl1.classList.remove('hidden'), tbl2.classList.remove('hidden')) :
    (tbl1.classList.add('hidden'), tbl2.classList.add('hidden'));
});

document.getElementById('u317').addEventListener('click', function () {
  const tbl1 = document.getElementById("tbl1"),
    tbl2 = document.getElementById("tbl2");
    tbl2.classList.contains('hidden') ?
      (tbl1.classList.remove('hidden'), tbl2.classList.remove('hidden')) :
      (tbl1.classList.add('hidden'), tbl2.classList.add('hidden'));
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="u362" class="ax_default">u362</div>
<span id="tbl1" class="hidden">Table 1</span>
<span id="tbl2" class="hidden">Table 2</span>
<div id="u317" class="ax_default">u317</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With the information provided in your question, I suppose that your error comes when hiding or showing your tables. I think you have to change your code at those lines:

```
    if (a.style.display === "none") {
      a.style.display = "block";
      b.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      a.style.display = "none";
      b.style.display = "none";
    }
```

for something like this:

```
    b.style.display = "none";
    if (a.style.display === "none") {
      a.style.display = "block";
    }
```

The new code will always hide **table b** when hitting **button a**. It doesn't matter the display status of **table a** because it doesn't really matter for hiding the rest of the tables. And only changes the display status of **table a** in case of being hidden.

You should do these changes also for each function of each button. I've also recommended to refactor all functions into a unique function and using it for all of the buttons you need.

Comment: thanks so much! however, the first button must be clicked twice once it is switched to the second table. is there a way to get around that?

Comment: You should create a second function changing __a__ per __b__ and __b__ per __a__. Then, set it on the second button and you have it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that the tables are invisible only after clicking the button, the appropriate table appears.
For future reference, please describe exactly what you want to use and you can use JsFiddle to show your code. Sometimes it is difficult to deduce from the descriptions what the writer had in mind :)

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener('click', e => {
    showTable(e.target.dataset.table);
  });
});

function showTable(idTable) {
  const tables = document.querySelectorAll('table');
  tables.forEach(table => {
    table.id === idTable ? table.style.display = 'block' : table.style.display = 'none';
  });
}
```

```css
table {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/skeleton/2.0.4/skeleton.min.css">
<button id="one" data-table="tb1">One</button>
<button id="two" data-table="tb2">Two</button>
<button id="tree" data-table="tb3">three</button>

<table id="tb1">
  <tr>
    <td>One</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="tb2">
  <tr>
    <td>Two</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table id="tb3">
  <tr>
    <td>Three</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```